# QSqlRelationalTableModel with LeftJoin mode and multiple relations displays nothing

Tags: qt, left-join, qtsql

when I'm setting only one relation, all is OK

```
model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db);
model->setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
model->setTable("someTable");
model->setRelation(model->fieldIndex("city"), QSqlRelation("city", "id", "city"));
model->select();
```

But when I set more than one relation, QTableView displays nothing.

```
model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db);
model->setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
model->setTable("someTable");
model->setRelation(model->fieldIndex("city"), QSqlRelation("city", "id", "city"));
model->setRelation(model->fieldIndex("country"), QSqlRelation("country", "id", "country"));
model->select();
```

And when I set **InnerJoin** mode it's all good (regardless of relations count)
How can I fix it? Is the problem naming of relation table?
P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise this question is quite old, but as it turns up in Google looking for the particular problem I thought I'd share my solution.

If, like me, you're stuck with Access you could also subclass QSqlRelationalTableModel and re-implement the selectStatement method to return proper SQL. In C++ this would be easy since you can just copy and correct the original source I guess. I'm working with PyQt and made it a Python class. I thought I'd share it here for others to benefit. It's not thoroughly tested, but works quite well for my situation.

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *


# Reimplementation of the selectStatement for use with Access databases
# since the standard method creates Access incompatible SQL statements on LEFT JOIN
class QSqlRelationalAccessTableModel(QSqlRelationalTableModel):

    joinMode = QSqlRelationalTableModel.InnerJoin
    relations = {}

    def selectStatement(self):
        query = ''

        if not self.tableName():
            return query
        if not self.relations:
            return QSqlRelationalTableModel.selectStatement(self)

        tList = ''
        fList = ''
        where = ''

        driver = self.database().driver()
        rec = self.record()
        tables = []

        # Count how many times each field name occurs in the record
        fieldNames = {}
        fieldList = []
        for idx in range(rec.count()):
            relation = self.relation(idx)
            if relation.isValid():
                name = relation.displayColumn()
                if driver.isIdentifierEscaped(name, QSqlDriver.FieldName):
                    name = driver.stripDelimiters(name, QSqlDriver.FieldName)

                relRec = self.database().record(relation.tableName())
                for i in range(relRec.count()):
                    if name.lower() == relRec.fieldName(i).lower():
                        name = relRec.fieldName(i)
                        break
            else:
                name = rec.fieldName(idx)
            fieldNames[name] = fieldNames.get(name, 0) + 1
            fieldList.append(name)

        for idx in range(rec.count()):
            relation = self.relation(idx)
            if relation.isValid():
                relTableAlias = 'relTblAl_%d' % idx
                if len(fList):
                    fList += ', '
                fList += relTableAlias + '.' + relation.displayColumn()

                # If there are duplicate field names they must be aliased
                if fieldNames[fieldList[idx]] > 1:
                    relTableName = relation.tableName().rsplit('.', 1)[0]
                    if driver.isIdentifierEscaped(relTableName, QSqlDriver.TableName):
                        relTableName = driver.stripDelimiters(relTableName, QSqlDriver.TableName)
                    displayColumn = relation.displayColumn()
                    if driver.isIdentifierEscaped(displayColumn, QSqlDriver.FieldName):
                        displayColumn = driver.stripDelimiters(displayColumn, QSqlDriver.FieldName)
                    fList += ' AS %s_%s_%s' % (relTableName, displayColumn, fieldNames[fieldList[idx]])
                    fieldNames[fieldList[idx]] -= 1

                if self.joinMode == QSqlRelationalTableModel.InnerJoin:
                    # Original Qt comment:
                    # this needs fixing!! the below if is borken.
                    # Use LeftJoin mode if you want correct behavior
                    tables.append(relation.tableName() + ' ' + relTableAlias)
                    if where:
                        where += ' AND '
                    where += self.tableName() + '.' + driver.escapeIdentifier(rec.fieldName(idx), QSqlDriver.FieldName)
                    where += ' = ' + relTableAlias + '.' + relation.indexColumn() + ')'
                else:
                    tables.append(' LEFT JOIN')
                    tables.append(relation.tableName() + ' ' + relTableAlias)
                    tables.append('ON')
                    clause = self.tableName() + '.' + driver.escapeIdentifier(rec.fieldName(idx), QSqlDriver.FieldName)
                    clause += ' = ' + relTableAlias + '.' + relation.indexColumn() + ')'
                    tables.append(clause)
            else:
                if len(fList):
                    fList += ', '
                fList += self.tableName() + '.' + driver.escapeIdentifier(rec.fieldName(idx), QSqlDriver.FieldName)

        if self.joinMode == QSqlRelationalTableModel.InnerJoin and len(tables):
            tList += ', '.join(tables)
            if len(tList):
                tList = ', ' + tList
        else:
            # left join!
            tList += ' '.join(tables)

        if not len(fList):
            return query

        # Assemble query parts
        tList = self.tableName() + tList
        if self.joinMode == QSqlRelationalTableModel.LeftJoin:
            tList = '(' * len(self.relations) + tList
        query = 'SELECT ' + fList + ' FROM ' + tList

        if self.joinMode == QSqlRelationalTableModel.InnerJoin:
            query = self.qAppendWhereClause(query, where, self.filter())
        else:
            # left join!
            if self.filter():
                query += ' WHERE (' + self.filter() + ')'

        if self.orderByClause():
            query += ' ' + self.orderByClause()

        return query

    # Make joinmode accessible
    def setJoinMode(self, joinMode):
        self.joinMode = joinMode
        QSqlRelationalTableModel.setJoinMode(self, joinMode)

    # Keep track of relations
    def setRelation(self, column, relation):
        if relation.isValid():
            self.relations[column] = relation
        else:
            if column in self.relations:
                del self.relations[column]

        QSqlRelationalTableModel.setRelation(self, column, relation)

    def qAppendWhereClause(self, query, clause1, clause2):
        if not len(clause1) and not len(clause2):
            return
        if not len(clause1) or not len(clause2):
            query += ' WHERE (' + clause1 + clause2 + ')'
        else:
            query += ' WHERE (' + clause1 + ') AND (' + clause2 + ') '

        return query
```

Answer (score 0):

So, really, the problem is **specific SQL syntax of MS Access**.
QSqlRelationTableModel generates SQL, which is incorrect for Access, when there is more than one relation column and mode is LeftJoin.
**My solution is to use SQLite.**

Comment: ms access has some advantages, you can visually set up all kind of joins in the database and simply read them afterwards in python. no need to program select statements in python. plus, access has real date field, which sqlite has not. on top you can create complex reports.